# What is preventing my footer links from being centered?

Tags: html, css

I've tried using

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: flex-end;
```

but my links still are not centered nor are they displayed at the bottom. I'm trying to get them to display as a row(which they are), centered, and at the bottom of the page. I've tried adding it to the footer class as well as the .footer ol

html code:

```
<footer class="footer">
    <ol>
        <li><a href="https://instagram.com"><img class="instagram-icon" src="images/instagram-icon.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://twitter.com"><img class="twitter-icon" src="images/twitter-icon.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com"><img class="linkedin-icon" src="images/linkedin-icon.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://github.com"><img class="github-icon" src="images/github-icon.png"></a></li>
    </ol>
</footer>
</html>
```

css code:

```
footer {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.footer ol {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.footer ol li {
    margin: 1em;
}

.footer ol li a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.footer ol li a:hover {color: rgb(83, 54, 150);}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
footer {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
.footer ol {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

Since the footer is flexed, you need to assign a width to the `ol` which is its child.
Then if you set the footer to `flex-direction: column` it should then put the `ol` at the bottom of the footer for you as well

Comment: Setting the width to 100% is good to know! Doing this did help center my ol but it is still displaying at the top of the page instead of the bottom. Any ideas?

This is how it now currently looks: https://imgur.com/a/EnHf4Zi